# Any way to see all moderator nominations?

Tags: support, election

The current [2015 Moderator Election](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1) page just shows 4 candidates ran for moderator; however, I know there were seven nominations. Is there any way to see withdrawn nominations?

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not seem to be available on the election site, it can be found with the Data Explorer. Since a `PostTypeId` of `6` means `ModeratorNomination`, the users that entered nominations for moderator election can be found with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/844236).

```
SELECT OwnerUserId AS [User Link],
       CONCAT('https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/', Id, '/revisions') AS 'Post Link'
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId=6 --PostTypeId of 6 is ModeratorNomination
  AND YEAR(CreationDate) = 2015
```

Thus, the following users made nominations:

- [X-27](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/31819/revisions)
- [zeffii](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/31820/revisions)
- [David](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-31822)
- [iKlsR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-31823)
- [gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-31827)
- [VRM](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-31830)
- [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/31832/revisions)

(The links for X-27, zeffii, and ideasman42 are to post revisions because there does not appear to be a way to link directly to withdrawn nominations. There were also [Comments on 2015 Moderator Election Nominations](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/844270).)

Comment: Awwww, that was a fun nomination XD